apollo-angular - hangs on `pending` status with network call
I intergrated angular18 with apollo-angular. when i try to fetch the call from gihub.com the network call hangs on pending state.
here is my provider for apollo-angular:
import { ApplicationConfig, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { ApolloClientOptions, ApolloLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/core";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { Apollo, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from "apollo-angular";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-angular/http";

export const githubData = {
  token: "ghp_M4T0mxxxxxxxUqnI4BHWyD6dGmQLk3Fovcb",
};

const uri = "https://api.github.com/graphql";

const header = setContext((operation, context) => ({
  headers: {
    Accept: "charset=utf-8",
  },
}));

const auth = setContext((operation, context) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  if (token === null) {
    return {};
  } else {
    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer " + githubData["token"],
      },
    };
  }
});

export function apolloOptionsFactory(): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  const httpLink = inject(HttpLink);
  const link = ApolloLink.from([header, auth, httpLink.create({ uri })]);
  return {
    link: link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

export const graphqlProvider: ApplicationConfig["providers"] = [
  Apollo,
  {
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: apolloOptionsFactory,
  },
];

My service :
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { gql, Query } from "apollo-angular";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class GitServiceService extends Query<Response> {
  document = gql`
    query {
      user(login: "3gwebtrain") {
        issues(first: 10) {
          nodes {
            title
            body
            closedAt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;
}

my component:
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterOutlet } from "@angular/router";

import { GitServiceService } from "./services/git-service.service";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrl: "./app.component.scss",
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  gitService = inject(GitServiceService);
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Hellow there");
    this.gitService.watch().valueChanges.subscribe((data) => console.log("data", data));
  }
}

when component loads, getting network status as pending and hanged.

could you replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back?

@NarenMurali but if I use http client it works fine. the issue is when I use angualr with apollo client

do you have SSR enabled? can you replicate the pending thing in the  stackblitz I shared?

@NarenMurali stackblitz not working properly. can I share git repo?

ok sure will check when I can

@NarenMurali will update. thanks

@NarenMurali I am not able to push my code. getting error because of keeping git token in env file. any suggesion?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This if condition will always return false, so your request is made without the auth token.
const auth = setContext((operation, context) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  if (token === null) { // <- token is never set so it will always go to if condition
    return {};
  } else {
    return {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer " + githubData["token"],
      },
    };
  }
});

Also the auth token seems to be of different length, can you set the auth token Generate Auth token
